# Understanding the Winograd Schema

Tags: nlp

What is the Winograd Schema?
A Winograd schema is a pair of sentences that differ in only one or two words and that contain an ambiguity that is resolved in opposite ways in the two sentences and requires the use of world knowledge and reasoning for its resolution.

Is this a good summary?

I do not understand why it is difficult to use NLP to resolve coreference in a winograd schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia page gives an example of a [Winograd Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winograd_schema_challenge), with the two instances:

1. The city councilmen refused the demonstrators a permit because *they* feared violence.
2. The city councilmen refused the demonstrators a permit because *they* advocated violence.

The question is, which noun group does *they* refer to. In sentence 1 it would be the city councilmen, in sentence 2 it would be the demonstrators.

How do you make that decision? The syntactic structure of the two sentences is identical, so it all hinges on the verbs *to fear* and *to advocate*. In order to make the right choice, you need to understand why councilmen fear violence, and would thus refuse it if demonstrators advovate it. This involves semantic and pragmatic knowledge, which are weak areas in NLP. It usually only works for limited domains, as it requires a lot of world knowledge (in this case about what you would expect from councilmen and demonstrators, and what the role of permits is).

So while syntax is easy to handle for current NLP, it is mostly irrelevant in resolving the Winograd Schema challenges.

Comment: I have another question that builds on this, could i send it to you personally? I could provide my email address so you don't have to expose any of your PII.

Comment: Just ask it on here and I'll do my best to answer it.

Comment: Sure, what are other types of coreference that NLP struggle to solve?

Comment: @SoMuchConfusion Please put it in a question, rather than a comment.

Comment: Sure, i have added a new question